# How to switch from Grub to Windows Boot Manager

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub

I have recently installed Debian 7 alongside Windows 7. Naturally they are in two different partitions and Debian was installed second. Debian has also installed GRUB as boot manager, but I would really like to switch to Windows Boot Manager, because will have to get rid of Debian eventually and I cannot risk to lose access to Windows. Is there a way to do just that?

Comment: Grub is not part of the OS, so you can remove the OS part and keep grub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> because will have to get rid of Debian eventually and I cannot risk to lose access to Windows. Is there a way to do just that?

The least action way (and my recommended path) is to just stay with `grub` for now and once you're done with Debian boot into recovery console from the Windows CD and run `BOOTREC /FIXMBR` which will make the Windows boot loader the active one.

The other route would be [something like this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/115993/how-to-add-ubuntu-to-the-windows-xp-boot-ini-file) where you install the grub bootloader to the partition boot sector, use `dd` to copy the boot sector to a file, transfer the file to the windows side somehow and then set up `boot.ini` to chain load to `grub` rather than the other way around.